# I keep hearing voices

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I've recently hit level 18 in Elder Scrolls Online. I've reached Grantwood and am doing various quests around the large tree in the middile, but I've started hearing voices after I kill something sometimes, anything from a level 1 monkey upwards. It says things like "you like killing, don't you?" and "how many more must die?"

I'm sure that there's no-one else around me when this has happened, and happens "in my (characters) head". I'm still fairly new to ESO and there's a lot of things that I'm getting used to, although this is...odd, to say the least.

Comment: Isn't that an awesome kind of quest breaking the habbits of just telling you everything straight away? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Turns out it's a cursed necklace from a quest. You find a necklace on a skeleton and when you return it to it's maker he explains it encourages the wearer to essentially commit suicide.

Jeeze.